# Import a package in a specific path in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

Hel lo I need to import a package called ete3:

```
from ete3 import EvolTree
```

Vut here is my question :

I have 2 localisations for this package :

- `~/path1/path2/ete3`
- `~/path1/path3/ete3`

and I changed manually some commande line in this one : `~/path1/path3/ete3`
But when I call ete3 in python3.7, it calles the one here : `~/path1/path2/ete3` but I would like to import the other one present here `~/path1/path3/ete3`

Does someone have an idea how to do it ? 
Thank you for your help

Comment: did you try to `pip install .` in the right package folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add empty file `__init__.py` in your folders so you can import them as

```
from path1.path3.ete3 import EvolTree
```

Like below

```
Project
 |    
 +-- path1
 |  |  
 |  +-- file __init__.py
 |  +-- path2
 |  |   |
 |  |   +-- __init__.py
 |  |   +-- ete3
 |  |   |   |
 |  |   |   +-- __init__.py
 |  +-- path3
 |  |   |
 |  |   +-- __init__.py
 |  |   +-- ete3  
 |  |   |   |
 |  |   |   +-- __init__.py
```